Develop OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow for Keycloak
I'm working on a Spring application and I want to integrate it with Keycloak so that users don't have to interact with Keycloak directly. I initially implemented the integration using the implicit flow, but when I attempted to switch to the auth code flow, I ran into some issues. I want my application to handle sessions and other related tasks instead of Keycloak managing them. Specifically, I need Keycloak to:

Verify the client credentials (client ID and secret)
Authenticate the user credentials (username and password)
Issue the authorization code
Fulfill any other requirements of the auth code flow

Which SDK should I use for this purpose, and how can I proceed with the integration? I am using Keycloak version 15.0.2.

"that users don't have to interact with Keycloak" you have obviously not understood what OAuth2 solves. Just don't use Keycloak in that case.
